# No 'Remove Widget' option for flutter with Android Studio in Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, ide

Widget options **(Alt+Enter)** are quite helpful in Flutter Development with Android Studio. It helps us to Move, Wrap, Add, Remove or Swap Widgets automatically, basically makes our life easy.

*Issue* : In my IDE the '**Remove widget**' option is missing. Check the image below for reference. With my fresh installation of Android Studio in two different computers, the option was never there since the beginning. I'm sure I never played or messed related configurations.

I know its not a big deal, but I'd love to have remove option as I play a lot with Widgets around and removing sometimes a pain.

Is there anything in configuration that I need to enable?

Android Studio : v3.5

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3787

Comment: Wow, this is it! I thought it'd duplicate the child widget. Looks like online references I've been seeing are bit old now. Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name has been changed from **Remove Widget** to **Replace widget with its children** but does the same thing.

**UPDATE**: Flutter has turned it back to `Remove Widget`.

Comment: It's still true, but there are some widgets, which can't be removed (yet?), like the most inner widgets, or `Obx` (from GetX package). I don't know why the latter.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** From Flutter **1.12.13+hotfix.5** • channel **stable** The option is now back to **`Remove Widget`**.